# I need a script that searches files for SSI and replaces the include with the actual HTML

Tags: python, html, ruby, bash, ssi

I am developing the front end code of a website which I will be handing over to some developers for them to integrate it with the backend. The site will be written in .NET but I'm developing the front end code with static HTML files (and a bit of javascript).

Because the header, footer and a few other elements are the same across all pages I am using Server Side Includes in my development environment. However, every time I hand the code to the developers I need to manually replace each SSI with the actual HTML by copying and pasting. This is starting to get tedious.

I have tried writing a bash script to do this but my bash knowledge is *extremely* limited so I have failed miserably (I'm not really sure where to start).

What I tried to achieve was:

- Loop through all the HTML files in my project
- Look for an include ( `<!--#include file="myfile.html"-->` )
- If one is found, replace the include with the HTML from the file specified in the include
- Keep doing this until there are no more includes and move on to the next file

Does anyone know of a script that can do this, or can point me in the right direction for achieving this myself? I'm happy for it to be in any language as long as I can run it on my Mac.

Thanks.

### EDIT

It is safe to assume that all instances of `<!--#include file="myfile.html"-->` are on their own line.

Comment: I've noticed I've had a downvote and a vote to close. Is there a more appropriate stackexchange site in which to post this question? Does it need rewording?

Comment: Looking through the help topic http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic I personally think this question comes under `practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession`. Someone in the programming profession must have come up against this problem before and no doubt will again.

Comment: if the myfile.html contains the code of your developers why do you need to replace the SSI include by hand ?? The code of this page is not in html/css/js ? or if the code they changed is the page that owns the SSI include they just should not remove it, shouldnt they ?

Comment: What if `myfile.html` has a `<\!--#include file="base.html"-->` line? Should it be also processed recursively?

Comment: @FoxMaSk I'm sorry you misunderstand - the code in the SSI is my own code, I'm using SSI for my own convenience. The code I give to the developers contains no SSI.

Comment: @TrueY That's a good question but in this instance there are no includes within includes so that doesn't matter.

Comment: ... and multiple #includes in one line? Are there any other characters in the #include line? Are there subdirs inside the project dir? Include file="..." can contain relative and or absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification does not cover every details, so I have the following assumptions.

1. The `<!--#include file="myfile.html"-->` line stays its own. Other characters are removed.
2. Included files does not contains additional includes.
3. In project directory no subdirs has to be checked.

In this case something like this can do the job. It is in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

search=${1:-./}

replace() {
  while read -r x; do
    if [[ "$x" =~ \<!--#include\ file=\"([^\.]+.html)\"--\> ]]; then
      cat "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}";
    else
      echo "$x"
    fi
  done <"$1"
}

while read f; do
  replace "$f" > tmp_$$.tmp && mv tmp_$$.tmp "$f"
done < <(find $search  -maxdepth 1 -name '*.html')
```

It reads all the `*.html` files in the specified directory (not recursively). If no args given it checks the current directory. For each line it calls `replace` function. `Replace` searches for include lines. If one found, then prints the content of the file to the stdout, otherwise the original line is presented.

Lets consider to files:

```
cat >master.html <<XXX
<html>
<!--#include file="myfile.html"-->
</html>
XXX

cat >myfile.html <<XXX
<title>
My file
</title>
XXX
```

Result:

```
$ cat master.html
<html>
<title>
My file
</title>
</html>
$ cat myfile.html
<title>
My file
</title>
```

I hope this could help...

Comment: Thank you TrueY. Unfortunately this isn't working. All it appears to do is remove the tab indents from my files but the includes are not being replaced.

Comment: Maybe the include pattern is different to what is in the Q. Write an `echo` before the `cat` line and put a `#` before the `>` char into the line where `replace` is called. Then it will print the result to stdout. 
Anyway what is your [tag:bash] version? Mine is 4.1.10. If Yours is too old it does not supports the pattern matching properly.

Comment: It was the \ in `<\!--#include file="myfile.html"-->`. I put that in because when I made another post and I wrote a block of code in Markdown I had to escape the `!` with a \. When you do it inline you don't need to but I hadn't noticed. This works a treat. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MrMisterMan: U R welcome! I corrected my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

On your dev machine, use your browser to display the web page, and then save the 'result' with an appropriate file name/in an output directory.

Thus, if you had mainfile.html which executed various time/last-mod directives and which included fileA.inc and fileB.inc at appropriate places, the resulting display (and save-able HTML file) will comprise all four/five components.

=dn